# Nav Bar Toggle Not Turning Text White

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-experience

**Question**

I can't understand why the text on the nav bar (when opened wit the Burger Menu) doesn't go white. I have tried everything to make it go white.

Please help me identify why the text won't go white when the hamburger menu is open.

**My Code**

```js
//Nav Bar

const navSlide = () =>{
    const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');

// Toggle Nav
    burger.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');


    //Animate Links
    navLinks.forEach((link, index)=>{
        if(link.style.animation){
            link.style.animation = '';
        } else {
        link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.5}s`
        }
   
    })
    //Burger Animation

    burger.classList.toggle('toggle');

})

}

navSlide();
```

```css
nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 8vh;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background-color: #ffffff;

}

.logo{
    color: #245871;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.nav-links{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 50%;
    
}

.nav-links li{
   list-style: none;
}

.nav-links a{
    color: #245871;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 18px;

}

.burger div{
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #245871;
    margin: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.burger{
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1024){
    .nav-links{
        width: 60%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 997px){
   body{
       overflow-x: hidden;
   }
   
   nav{
       color: white;
   }

   .test{
       color: white;
   }
    .nav-links{
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        height: 92vh;
        top: 8vh;
        background-color: #245871;
        color: white;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 50%;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    }
    .nav-links a li{
        opacity: 1;
        color: white;
    }
    .burger{
      display: block;
    }
}

.nav-active{
    transform: translateX(0%);
    color: white;
}

@keyframes navLinkFade{
    from{
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(50px);
    } to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
}


.toggle .line1{
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
}

.toggle .line2{
    opacity: 0;
}

.toggle .line3{
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
}
```

```html
 <body>
       
        <nav>
            <div class="logo">
                    <h4>Website</h4>    
            </div>
            <ul class="nav-links">
                <li class=".test"><a href="#">xxxx</a></li>
                <li class=".test"><a href="#">xxx</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">xxxx</a></li>
                <!-- browsers -->
                <li><a href="#">Free xxx</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">xxxx</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="burger">    
                <div class="line1"></div>
                <div class="line2"></div>
                <div class="line3"></div>

            </div>
        </nav>
```

**Help Greatly Appreciated!**

The issue appears to be in the classes that I am adding (or making applicable through the media queries, that are not actually working in practice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change,

```
.nav-links a li{
    opacity: 1;
    color: white;
 }
```

**to**

```
.nav-links li a{
    opacity: 1;
    color: white;
}
```

Please make sure you follow the right order in mentioning the css selector.

You have mentioned `.nav-links a li` but actual order is `.nav-links li a`

Modified **Snippet** as follows,

```js
//Nav Bar

const navSlide = () =>{
    const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');

// Toggle Nav
    burger.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');


    //Animate Links
    navLinks.forEach((link, index)=>{
        if(link.style.animation){
            link.style.animation = '';
        } else {
        link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.5}s`
        }
   
    })
    //Burger Animation

    burger.classList.toggle('toggle');

})

}

navSlide();
```

```css
nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 8vh;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background-color: #ffffff;

}

.logo{
    color: #245871;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.nav-links{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 50%;
    
}

.nav-links li{
   list-style: none;
}

.nav-links a{
    color: #245871;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 18px;

}

.burger div{
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #245871;
    margin: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.burger{
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1024){
    .nav-links{
        width: 60%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 997px){
   body{
       overflow-x: hidden;
   }
   
   nav{
       color: white;
   }

   .test{
       color: white;
   }
    .nav-links{
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        height: 92vh;
        top: 8vh;
        background-color: #245871;
        color: white;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 50%;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    }
    .nav-links li a{
        opacity: 1;
        color: white;
    }
    .burger{
      display: block;
    }
}

.nav-active{
    transform: translateX(0%);
    color: white;
}

@keyframes navLinkFade{
    from{
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(50px);
    } to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
}


.toggle .line1{
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
}

.toggle .line2{
    opacity: 0;
}

.toggle .line3{
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
}
```

```html
<body>
       
        <nav>
            <div class="logo">
                    <h4>Website</h4>    
            </div>
            <ul class="nav-links">
                <li class=".test"><a href="#">xxxx</a></li>
                <li class=".test"><a href="#">xxx</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">xxxx</a></li>
                <!-- browsers -->
                <li><a href="#">Free xxx</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">xxxx</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="burger">    
                <div class="line1"></div>
                <div class="line2"></div>
                <div class="line3"></div>

            </div>
        </nav>
```